# how do I create a text from data I have from a set?

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

I have data (urls) stored in a SET. I want to grab that data and create a text file from it.

I later want to create a dictionary where the data from the text file is the key and a certificate is the value.

here's my code. found is the set.

```
d1={}
f=open('found.txt','w')
f.write(found) # error appears here
f.close()


for domain in open('found.txt','r'):
    cert=ssl.get_server_certificate((domain, 443))
    if domain not in d1:
        d1[domain]=cert
```

the set contains domains that had been crawled.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on how you want to format the text file -- At it's simplest, you'd write each element and then a newline.  You could do that with:

```
with open('found.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(url + '\n' for url in found)
```

Here I've used a context manager to mange the file closing.  I would recommend that you get in the habit of always using them when working with files.

Your error is happening because `file.write` *requires* you to pass in a string.  You're passing in a `set` which it doesn't know how to handle.  An alternative which changes only one line of your original code would be:

```
f.write('\n'.join(found))
```

but, in general, I like the first way better.  You store less intermediate data in memory so it has a smaller footprint.